# JSTree and Cakephp URL Helper

Tags: jstree, cakephp-3.0

i am trying to to build a tree menu with JStree and Cakephp.
My Problem is that i don't understand how to build a dynamic Url to call the Controller.

My index.ctp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Hier der jQuery-Code */
    /* alert('Hallo Welt'); */


    $('#tree').jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : {
                "url" : "<?php echo $this->Url->build(['controller'=>'partscatalogs','action'=>'index.json']);?>",
                "data" : function (node) {
                    return { "id" : node.id };
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div class="row-fluid">

    <div id ="tree" class="col-md-3">
    menu

    </div>

    <div id= "stage" class="col-md-9">
        stage

    </div>
</div>
```

My Partscatalogscontroller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\Controller\Component\RequestHandlerComponent;
use Cake\Network\Http\Client;
use Cake\Core\Configure;


class PartscatalogsController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->autorender=false;
    #debug($id);
    ########
    # Startknoten des ETK festlegen
    ########
        $tree=array(
                    ["id"=>"EWM", "text"=>"EWM_Text","children"=>true],
                    ["id"=>"Teamwelder", "text"=>"Teamwelder_Text","children"=>true]

            );
        #debug($tree);
        $this->set(compact('tree', $tree));
        $this->set('_serialize', 'tree');
    }

}
```

The above example works fine, but i dont understand how to call the controller in the way

"partscatalogs/index.json?foo=bar"

to expand the tree with lazy loading.

Could someone be so kind and give me a hint or tell me where i can read more about this.
I read at the Homepage of JStree but could not find anything helpful.
Maybe i was looking wrong?

Many thanks in advance for any hint or help!

Greetings

Dirk

Comment: I don't really get what exactly the problem is. You say the example works fine (wich might be true, even though adding the `.json` extension to the action is the wrong way), so what exactly does "... _i dont understand how to call the controller in the way_ ..." mean?

Comment: hello ndm, thanks for reading my question and sorry for my bad english. I can not explain better what i mean, so i will try it on my own. If i find a solution, i will post it. I think then it will be clear what i wanted and maybe it helps someone else.

Comment: In case it has anything to do with generating URLs with extensions, check [**the `_ext` option**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions).

Comment: When using the _ext option i can build the url tthat way "url" : "<?php echo $this->Url->build(['controller'=>'partscatalogs','action'=>'index',"_ext" => "json"]);?>". But my main Problem is how to pass a variable to the controller to retrieve the data from the leaf i would like to open

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. Are you asking how to create a URL with query string values? Or maybe how to access query string data (namely the `id` key which jsTree automatically appends to the specified URL if I'm not mistaken) in your controller action?

Comment: I need to create the url with  query string value

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls**